# one to many relationship query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query a number of tables that have records with a one to many relationship.  The records I need are the `myid` values with the following criteria:

They have to have the attribute

1. `firstcode` with values of 1, 3, 8, 200. It can be any combination of these codes or all of them.
2. `secondstuff` is also related to the `firstcode`; each `firstcode` will have a `secondstuff` value.  The `secondstuff` values I am interested in are X, Y, Z (there are many others).

The problem I am running into is sometimes the `myid` record comes back, and it has 4 of the `firstcode` values, but not all of the `firstcode` values have the correct `secondstuff` value. Here is my query:

```
Select MYID
from myidtable a
where myid in (select myid1
              from dadtable b
              join  momtable c
              on b.dadid=c.momdadid
              join kidtable d
              on c.momid  = d.kidid
              where d.firstcode in (1, 3,8, 200)
              and c.secondstuff in ('X', 'Y’, 'Z')
              and thedate > to_date('12/31/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        )
```

So in some cases I get a record back that has for example:

```
Myid  firstcode secondstuff
34      1           X
34      3           M
34      8           X
```

As you can see, firstcode 3 has a secondstuff of M, as such, myid =34 shouldn’t be returned.  What I am looking for is something like the following:

```
Myid  firstcode secondstuff
 35    1           X
 35    3           Z
 35    8           X
```

In this case, all my first codes that were associated with the myid table have the correct secondstuff values. Please note, its fine if some of the first code values are not associated with the myid table; Any two firstcodes will suffice.

Comment: Please, provide some sample data and desired output for it.

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided it seems that there are 2 columns with same name  in two different tables. You are filtering in `kidtable` and while displaying you are accessing column from a different table. Make sure that you filter `secondstuff` column from all the tables in which it is present.